# Check if string is in array

Tags: python, list, unicode

i'm trying to check if some strings are in one array, like this:

```
intact_columns = [...]
for key, value in obj.iteritems():
    if not key in intact_columns:
       print key
```

The problem is: there are items like this in the array: `Reten\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o (RET)`

And the strings that i'm iterating over are like this: `Retenção (RET)`

How could i parse the strings inside the array to look like normal strings?

Comment: Have you tried: `if not key.encode('utf8') in intact_columns` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you are using the different encoding in both the strings. I am not the sure about the encoding type. It is safe to decode these to `utf-8` (or *utf-16*) and then check. For example:

```
>>> my_list = ['Reten\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o (RET)', 'blah blah ...']
>>> my_string = 'Retenção (RET)'
>>> my_list[0].decode('utf-8')
u'Reten\xe7\xe3o (RET)'
>>> my_string.decode('utf-8')
u'Reten\xe7\xe3o (RET)'
```

Both holds the same decoded value

Comment: solid answer imho ;)

Answer (score 1):

first you really need to understand the encoding ... at a guess the items in the array are utf8 ... the items you are checking apear to be unicode

```
if key.encode("utf8") in intact_columns:
```

note that i dont know what encoding is being used... (but utf8 is usually a pretty safe guess)

an aside about encodeing

```
bytestring.decode('utf8') # -> results in unicode
unicodestr.encode('utf8') # -> results in bytestring
```

in python3 you cannot encode/decode unless it is the appropriate type(unicode/bytestring). in python2 it will try and implicitly encode or decode for you if you hand it the wrong thing... which is where you are running into issues

Comment: `'Retenção (RET)'.encode('utf-8')` gives `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)` error